# PowerShell Azure Blob Storage Exlude Specific ContentType

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to list all blobs that are not PDF files. How would I do that?
I know that I can list all files like this:

```
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountKey XXX -StorageAccountName YYY
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'containerName' -Context $StorageContext
```

And if I want to fitler for a specific content type, png in the case below, I would change the second line to this:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'containerName' -Context $StorageContext -Blob *.png
```

But how can I display anything besides a specific content type. In my case I would want to list everything besides PDFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the command below.

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'containerName' -Context $StorageContext | Where-Object {!($_.Name -like '*.pdf')}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi joy, what about if a file named `aa.pdf.txt`?

Comment: @IvanYang If so, it will also be included in the result, because it is a `.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you. You're so great and kind:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How would I apply one more filter. I want the files LastModified property to be less than some Date I specify?

Comment: I solved it and added another answer for it. Thanks again @JoyWang

Answer (score 0):

I extended the version from @JoyWan to apply another filter. I want to show all files less than some date:

```
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) # get date 3 moths before

$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountKey XXX -StorageAccountName YYY
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'containerName' -Context $StorageContext | where {($_.Name -notlike '*.pdf' -and $_.LastModified -le $filterDate)}
```

This example would show all files older than 3 months.